# Given an array of objects, find the object with a particular key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

Given an array of objects, what is the best way to find the object with a particular key in JS?

Using jQuery and underscoreJS is fine. I'm just looking for the easiest / least code answer.

**Example:**
An array of objects, where each object has a "name". Find the object with a particular "name".

`var people = [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}];`

**My current solution:**
Pass in the array, the key (e.g. "name"), and the value (e.g. "C").

```
function getObject(myArray, searchKey, searchValue) {
  myArray.forEach(function(element){
    if (element[searchKey] == searchValue) {
      return element;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You probably want `filter`.

Comment: Too bad ES6 isn't really supported yet: `return arr.find(el => el[searchKey] === searchValue);`

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy It still is in draft :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use Underscore.js's [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) function, like this

```
console.log(_.where(people, {
    "name": "C"
}));
# [ { name: 'C' } ]
```

This returns all the objects in the array, which exactly matches the object we pass as the second argument.

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye - I'll accept the answer when the timer is up. Do you also happen to know how I can delete this from the array? Looks like deletion requires me to know the index of the element in the array.

Comment: @DonnyP You can use `_.filter` as shown in other answers, which will give a new array without the unwanted elements. So, we can ditch the old array and start using the new array.

Answer (score 1):

Using [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var people = [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}];

var filteredPeople = _.filter(people, function(obj){
    return obj['name'] == 'C';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredPeople)) // [{"name":"C"}]
```

If you want an array without the matched object(s), use [_.reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject):

```
var filteredPeople = _.reject(people, function(obj){
    return obj['name'] == 'C';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredPeople)) // [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}]
```

Comment: `filter` is only appropriate if you want an array of all matches. To find just one match, it would be [`_.find`](https://underscorejs.org/#find).

Answer (score 1):

You should go with [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) of jQuery

```
var people = [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}];

var obj1= jQuery.grep(people,function(n,i){return (n.name=='A')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any custom library you can also do this. Please take a look at the following code

```js
var people = [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}],
    match=function(element){
      return element.name==="A";
    };
console.log(people.filter(match));
```

But it is kind of static code . I don't know how to pass the key and value to the match() function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised not to find the obvious answer here, so: To do that with Underscore, you'd use [`_.find`](https://underscorejs.org/#find):

```
function getObject(myArray, searchKey, searchValue) {
    return _.find(myArray, function(entry) { return entry[seachKey] === searchValue; });
}
```

You don't need Underscore for this, though; JavaScript's array type has `find` (as of ES5):

```
function getObject(myArray, searchKey, searchValue) {
    return myArray.find(function(entry) { return entry[searchKey] === searchValue; });
}
```

As of ES2015+, you can make it more concise with an arrow function and destructuring:

```
function getObject(myArray, searchKey, searchValue) {
    return myArray.find(({[searchKey]: value}) => value === searchValue);
}
```

Live example of that last one:

```js
function getObject(myArray, searchKey, searchValue) {
    return myArray.find(({[searchKey]: value}) => value === searchValue);
}

const people = [{name: "A"}, {name: "B"}, {name: "C"}];
console.log(getObject(people, "name", "C"));
```